# Where and how to get a Carnet de Passage for a Pakistani Vehicle?

Tags: europe, road-trips, asia, motorcycles, carnet-de-passage

I am planning to travel to Europe on my Suzuki jeep. Where and how can I get a Carnet de Passage in Pakistan?
I might even decide to do it on a motorbike if the Carnet turns out to be super expensive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AIT/FIA act as guarantors for the Carnet de Passages en Douane and the [FIA](http://www.fia.com/mobility-world-motion/cpd/international-cpd-network) do not include Pakistan in an extensive list of countries under “Where to get your CPD”. Seems may not be available in Pakistan, but it might be worth contacting Automobile Association of Pakistan and Motorsport Association of Pakistan as these are both FIA members.

The [<strike>RAC</strike>](http://www.rac.co.uk/pdfs/driving-abroad/carnet-de-passage-information.aspx) has some cost information, though other issuing organisations presumably differ.

Sorry, that link is dead (there is no longer any representative in the UK that issues CDPs).